# Best way to search a row in google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

So, been looking at search functions in google spreadsheet, and find it difficult to figure out a smooth way to find which column on row one contain a specific value.

To explain a bit more, its a simple allocation spreadsheet, basically who works as what on which project for how long, and as we have a number of different pipelines, I wanted the pipelines separated. So I created a sheet for each, set up the first five collumns so contain all kind of useful info (like resource, project, project role, chargeable, client) then the rest of the collumns represents weeks, so each collumn have the date of the Monday, and all eight sheets have the same setup, so column 6 to 28 contains the date of the following Monday, allowing me to predict resource allocation a total of 22 weeks or thereabouts.

The next step is to create a report (sheet 1) which tells me by resource how busy they are, either as summary or as detailed+summary, and put some colour in if anyone is allocated to many or to few days in a specific week. 
I also wanted to view to allow me to specify a date, easy enough, two drop down menus. First is the list of dates row one sheet two, second one is the same list, so the user can in specify 27/01/2014 - 03/04/2014 from the drop down list.
Now comes my issue, I want to retrieve the numerical value of the columns matching the date, so if the start date is in column F I want a variable with 6 in. And end date is in M thats 14.

Anyone have any good suggestions how this can be done?

Tried reading the row and searching it as an array, did not work particularly well

```
var vcSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Office");
var range = vcSheet.getRange(1,1,1,28);
var dates = range.getValue();

var strCol = dates.indexOf(dtStart);
var stpCol = dates.indexOf('Task');
Browser.msgBox('Found start col on ' + strCol + ' end col on ' + stpCol);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried .**getValues**(), as opposed to .getValue()? Maybe something like;

```
var dates=range.getValues();
for (i in dates[0]) {
    if (dates[0][i].indexOf(dtStart)>-1) {  some stuff  }
}
```